# Was J.R.R. Tolkien a fan of the original Star Trek series?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tos, j-r-r-tolkien

I have been doing some research on the Internet today trying to find out if J.R.R Tolkien had been a fan of the original Star Trek series, which ran from 1966 to 1969. Since Tolkien died in 1973, it makes me wonder if he had watched the original series and whether he may have given his opinion about the program.

Was J.R.R. Tolkien a fan of the original Star Trek series?

Comment: I am not certain when STar Trek was first shown in the UK, so I don't know whether Tolkien had many opportunities to see it at friend's houses.

Comment: @M.A.Golding - It was shown in 1969 on the BBC. There was ample time for him to have seen the first couple of seasons as he was retired from teaching at this point in his life.

Comment: If he ever was, he probably wasn't after [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BC35cQKHwzg)

Comment: @Machavity - That's a really good point. Tolkien supposedly asked his publisher to look into whether this song breached his copyright, so clearly he was aware of it (and maybe Leonard Nimoy) in general terms

Comment: What on Earth would inspire one to wonder whether an English don -- linguist and developer of fantasy myth where all of the Good Guys are pre-Industrial -- would be a fan of the highest of high-tech TV shows???

Comment: @RonJohn, I just thought that since Tolkien was a writer of epic fantasy novels, he may have been interested in Star Trek since it is also an epic fantasy.

Comment: ST:TOS is epic *fantasy*????

Comment: @RonJohn - If it were me, I would question the "epic" part more than the "fantasy" part. Seemingly every other week, some god-like entity would show up that could could do anything with a wave of its hand, the whole basis of their transportation is something that is almost certainly physically impossible, they could go back in time whenever and potentially change things (also not likely on the possible side), telepathic powers were a fact of life, and so on and so forth.

Comment: All of that fits fantasy rather well, with some technobabble dressing. The epic part is what is doubtful: on the original series, there was no overarching heroic quest, and the crew were more often relatively ordinary people than not (or extraordinary like Tyson Gay, not Gilgamesh). It was more like the "problem of the week," and the goal was exploration and diplomacy, not fighting some great threat.

Comment: @RonJohn, “To boldly go where no man has gone before”. Isn’t that epic? Also, it could be argued that things like warp drive, transporters, and godlike beings like Q are the stuff of fantasy. So, I think that it’s fair to categorize Star Trek as being an epic fantasy.

Comment: By your definition, there is no difference between fantasy and "future" science fiction.  That's arrant nonsense.

Comment: Star Trek:TOS is explicitly a *Space Western* (as Roddenberry called it: "_Wagon Train_ to the stars", referring to an episodic Western on tv at the time). Also, Tolkien really didn't like Dune, which was much more obviously a space fantasy epic, so he had likes and dislikes.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

**Probably not.** Tolkien didn't own a television and wasn't really interested in modern culture, preferring to attend the opera, lectures on poetry, and listen to occasional programs on the wireless. He certainly watched *some* TV (when visiting his brother's house he noted that they had watched the cricket and tennis while drinking whisky) and while there's no evidence that he didn't watch Star Trek on someone else's set, it seems unlikely.

> He never spent money carelessly; he and Edith did not install any
> electrical gadgets in the home, for they had never been accustomed to
> them and did not imagine that they needed them now. **Not only was there
> no television in the house**, but no washing-machine or dishwasher
> either.
>
> <sub><sup>[JRR Tolkien: A Biography](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/7336.J_R_R_Tolkien)</sup></sub>

He described the radio in *extremely* disparaging terms.

> *Only in one way was I better off: wireless was not invented. I daresay it had some potential for good, but **it has in fact in the main become a weapon for the fool, the savage, and the villain to afflict the minority with, and to destroy thought.** Listening in has killed listening.*
>
> <sub><sup>[Tolkien Letter 61 (to his son, Christopher)](https://tolkiengateway.net/wiki/Letter_61)</sup></sub>

I think we can be reasonably sure that if he was even aware of Star Trek (noting that when introduced to film megastar Ava Gardner at the height of her fame, he [hadn't *heard* of her, let alone seen one of her films](https://tolkiengateway.net/wiki/Letter_267)), that he would have had little or no interest in watching it.

Comment: To add, Star Trek was originally broadcast in the UK at 5:15 (in the timeslot previously occupied by Doctor Who). And that was the days when you watched a program when it was broadcast or not at all.
http://space-doubt.blogspot.com/2014/10/star-trek-on-bbc-part-one.html?m=1

Comment: He was almost a Luddite in his personal philosophy.  Asimov noted that he depicted morder as using almost industrial technology, creating pollution in their wake.  Asimov saw this as part of Tolkien's misguided obsession with Master/Servant rural English life that had disappeared.

Comment: @MarkRogers I think a clearer example of Tolkien's distaste of industrialism comes from the Scouring of the Shire, rather than Mordor!

Comment: Another point worth mentioning, is that all the known instances of Tolkien watching sports on other people's televisions are from 1972 and 1973, after his wife died, and after Star Trek finished airing.

Comment: @ibid - He definitely had  access to a Faculty TV Room while working at Oxford

Comment: @GaryMyers, 05:15 in the morning? Or 17:15 in the afternoon? The first one sounds implausible, even for a niche show, but why would the second be a problem? (Ok, the linked page does say 5.15 **pm**)

Comment: @GaryMyers - He was retired at the point that the show was broadcast, so it being shortly after working hours (e.g. 9-5) wouldn't have been an issue

Comment: Much as we all love TOS I suspect it wouldn't have interested a _real_ story teller any more than any of the rest of the TV wasteland .... (maybe Twilight Zone though?)

Comment: "or dishwasher either" - I find that an odd thing to specifically call out, as while not necessarily *uncommon*, a dish washer is still far from a given in a British household even today.  You were considered privileged if you had one in the 1990s...

Comment: That 2nd quote most certainly applies to TV today, as well! "_Watching has killed thinking._"

Comment: ... and the Internet in general and social media in particular.

Comment: @ibid - it was no longer produced after 1969, but I'm pretty sure it was still airing after that. At least, I think was watching it in that timeframe.

Comment: @Edheldil ... and books themselves! (If Plato/Socrates are to be believed)

Comment: "Asimov saw this as part of Tolkien's misguided obsession with Master/Servant rural English life that had disappeared" @MarkRogers

That's kind of a funny observation. From the times I have seen LoTR I get the impression that the Shire is Tolkiens idea of an ideal society. A place where people do not care about power and ruling over one another, but rather living and enjoying life.